# Concept difference between prejudiced and puritanical

Tags: nouns

When I read the translation of the word puritanical in my language I thought it has a positive meaning but reading the English description I felt it more like prejudiced,  which side does this word take? Positive or negative meaning?

The example in the dictionary was:

> His puritanical parents saw any kind of pleasure as the road to
>   damnation.

This reflects to me the meaning for the word prejudiced the most, but from the translation in Persian I got someone more spiritual, not more strict.

Comment: What did you discover when you looked up these words in a dictionary?

Comment: @WS2  the example in the dictionary was: his puritanical parents saw any kind of pleasure as the road to damnation,this reflects me the meaning for the word prejudiced the most, but from the translation in Persian I got someone more spiritual, not more strict

Comment: *Puritanical* and *prejudiced* are quite different, and nearly any dictionary makes this clear. Don't just read an example sentence; try to understand the definitions give. And even with that example sentence, note that the particular "prejudice" involved (if you want to call it that) is prejudice against *pleasure*. Puritanism is a very particular thing, even if you choose to characterize it completely as a set of prejudices.

Comment: Maybe the translator was confusing Puritan and puritanical.  Also maybe purist and puritanical.  (There's nothing wrong with a person holding himself to stringent expectations regarding his own behavior -- as might be the case for a Puritan.)  We can call him puritanical, though, when he gets judgmental about other people not following his rules for himself.

Answer (score 4):

The Puritans were an English religious sect of the late 16th century that fought against the national church (and especially Catholicism). Some of them decamped to the United States, where they established their own religious communities that became known for the severity of their own religious views and their intolerance of any others.  American author H L Mencken described puritanism as ""the haunting fear that someone, somewhere, may be happy", and particularly when sexual practice and pleasure was concerned. *Puritanism* has the connotation of censorious prudishness, and it's almost always used in a negative sense.

Here a vernacular usage from a [blogger](http://norightturn.blogspot.com/2008/03/republicans-sex-and-impeachment.html) in 2008:

> At the heart of this problem though is Americans' - and particularly
>   Republicans' - attitudes about democracy and sex. They think the sex
>   lives of elected officials are everyone's business, and that private
>   sexual behaviour affects whether people do their jobs properly. It
>   doesn't. All this **puritanical** attitude brings is endless scandal
>   and ruined lives.

Someone who is *prejudiced* is someone who has taken an position unwarranted by evidence (that is "pre-judged"). The position is almost always against something or someone, unless explicitly indicated otherwise, and the word has come to mean bigoted.

Comment: Thank you so much,  very great answer,  by the way is there a word for a religious person whose acts and way of beliefs seems positive to others?

Comment: @Farzad64 That could become a decent question rather than a comment (supplementary questions in comments are frowned upon). Do search first though; because it's a good question it may have been asked before.

Comment: @AndrewLeach thank you, I think it's hard for me to find the right keywords to look it up though...

Comment: @Farzad64 Obvious words to search on are [positive religious](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=positive+religious). The top answer there gives some words; I'm sure you could build a question on that if it doesn't actually help by itself.

Comment: @Farzad64 If you mean someone whose religious beliefs seem positive to those of a different religion, then alas, I doubt it. Most religions partition the world into believers and infidels.

Comment: @Farzad64 At one time [devout](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/devout) was a generally postitve word but these days devout people are viewed with more suspicion. However [saintly](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/saintly) still carries mainly positive connotations. People like [St {or Mother} Theresa of Calcutta](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/saintly) are often referred to as 'saintly'.

Comment: It does seem that other similar terms tend to acquire a similar taint.  *Fundamentalism* is, technically speaking, a "neutral" term for the trait of strictly adhering to some set of principles, and by that definition Puritans were fundamentalists.  But that term has also shifted to convey a sense of being overzealous to the point of being prejudiced (or worse).

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to imagine a [puritanical](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/puritanical) person who is unprejudiced (although some of the earliest Quakers may have come close) but it's easy to imagine someone leading a distinctly unpuritanical life of sex, drugs and rock and roll but holding very prejudiced views of other races, people of other sexual orientations, liberals, conservatives, religious people (including puritans), promotors of healthy lifestyles and so on.

Most of us have prejudices of one sort or another but not all prejudiced people can be described as puritanical.